# SOAP Server in PHP - how to write WSDL file - tips

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have quite complex (authentication, logs, ...) [SOAP server](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) (standard PHP extension). Everything is working fine but I want to know if there is any tool for creating / generating WSDL file? All changes I do manually and there are two problems:

1. localhost

I have for testing reasons the same SOAP server on localhost - I need the same WSDL file and only difference is in url addresses which point to localhost. I copy & paste lines from one (localhost) file to other (production) file and this is good way to do mistake.

1. new function
   When I want to add function to WSDL it takes me "long" time to understand again wsdl because it has more that 1000 lines.

I'm quite new to SOAP and also WSDL - I'm looking for good (and free) WSDL editor or tool to gererate WSDL file.

Answer (score 0):

Try [WSO2 WSF/PHP Library](http://wso2.org/library/wsf/php). It can generate WSDL right from your code.

Comment: Pavel's link is broken leads to a 404

Comment: @MikeVolmar, I think the library is dead now, but the code is available here https://github.com/wso2/wsf/tree/master/php

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, you can take a look into the [WSDL Editor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Introduction_to_the_WSDL_Editor).

You can also create a build script, that parses an existing WSDL (it's XML) and replace specific values (like the hostname) with another one to a target file.

Comment: How / where can I donwload it? I have eclipse and I'm not fan of it. Because you must do things like this: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636543/how-can-i-make-the-home-key-put-me-at-position-1-in-eclipse) to have "working editor"... by the way content assist is not working inside array :(

Comment: ??? - No idea to which problems you refer to, in any case, this is the project the WSDL Editor is part of: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/ - you can download it there or use the indigo update site. It's part of the Web tools platform.

Answer (score 0):

Creating WSDL file from scratch can be very complicated and error prone. To ease this process, you can use an IDE to generate the WSDL file for your PHP functions and pass it as a parameter to your PHP SoapServer class. Check out this simple tutorial on [How to generate wsdl for php native soap class](http://osarogabriel.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-generate-wsdl-for-php-soap-server.html)

Comment: all of the images in this url example by Osaro are broken links, which is too bad since I would like to use Netbeans to make a wsdl